# prevent page posting back and set a hidden field value

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Using jquery, I want to prevent a postback and set a hidden field value.

**JavaScript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function HideImage() {
        $("#divclose").hide();
        $("#hdnClose").val("0");
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

**Aspx Page**

```
<div id="divclose">
    <asp:imagebutton id="closeImage" runat="server" imageurl="close.gif" onclientclick="return HideImage()" imagealign="Right" />
    <input type="hidden" id="hdnClose" value="0" />
<div>
```

The page is refresh when set:

```
$("#hdnClose").val("0");
```

Comment: do you really need an ImageButton there? If you don't want the submit behavior, use a simple button or an image.

Comment: I think you have to put proper syntax like -> onclientclick="return HideImage();"

Comment: Luizgrs its requirement that there put a image button and its look perfect but i want to prevent the postback on click of that button and set hidden field value b'coz i want to use for next portion.

Comment: Shirish  its not a big problem b'coz javascript function work properly and i get the alert on there and i checked that bt what i want that i already told so help me on that.

Comment: @Narashi Hadiya yes you are right but just try this -> onclientclick="return HideImage();" if still not works then say..

Comment: i tried dude when u told me then first i do that bt still i don't get the answer.